# Logical form of the statements

Tags: logic

I have two statements taken from the book: *How to prove it*.

S1 :
We’ll have either a reading assignment or homework problems,but we
won’t have both homework problems and a test.

S2:  You won’t go skiing, or you will and there won’t be any snow.

For S1:

Let R : We will have a reading assignment.

H :  We will have homework problems.

T: We will have a test.

S1 in logical form : $(R \lor H) \land \neg{(H \land T)}$

For S2:

Let T : You will go skiing.

V:  There will be snow.

S2 in logical form : $\neg{T} \lor (T \land \neg{V})$

Can you verify my analysis?

Comment: It seems correct. It's worth noting that S2 can be simplified to $\neg T \lor \neg V$.